# Webpack 2 randomly fails in different files until I save them

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-2

The error I get once and once again is this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

The same happened in three different machines, always with different files that fail.

When I trace the file that is breaking and I open it and save it webpack re compiles and the error disappears. I can trace it because in the call stack I find this where it fails:

```
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__base_base_icon__ = __webpack_require__(567);
```

In this case I know that is the base_icon.jsx file. It happens randomly with different files. There is some cache or something like that in webpack 2 that is producing this weird behavior?

This same project in Webpack 1 worked perfectly. This problem has appear since we migrated to Webpack 2.

My webpack configuration is the following:

```
var indexFile = '/index.html'
if (PROJECT) {
    indexFile = '/projects/'+PROJECT+'/'+PROJECT+'_index.html'
}

const common = {
    entry: {
        main: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, 'src/main.jsx')],
        themes: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, 'src/projects/themes/themes_main.jsx')],
        common: [
            //'bodymovin',
            path.join(__dirname, 'src/animations/bodymovin'),
            'check-types',
            'classnames',
            'moment',
            'qs',
            'react',
            'react-addons-css-transition-group',
            'react-addons-shallow-compare',
            'react-addons-transition-group',
            'react-css-modules',
            'react-date-picker',
            'react-dom',
            'react-dropzone',
            'react-redux',
            'react-router',
            'react-router-redux',
            'redux',
            'redux-form',
            'redux-infinite-scroll',
            'redux-saga',
            'reselect',
            'superagent',
            'superagent-defaults',
            'superagent-promise-plugin',
            'react-intercom'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/assets'),
        publicPath: publicPath,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            config: 'config/'+config+'.js'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]&sourceMap',
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                plugins: function(webpack) {
                                    return [
                                        postcssImport,
                                        precss,
                                        hexrgba,
                                        cssnext,
                                        inlineSvg,
                                        svgo,
                                        math
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', ['es2015', {modules: false}], 'stage-0'],
                        compact: false
                    }
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?name=media/fonts/[name].[ext]'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=media/image/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(webm|mp4)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=media/video/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

const commonPlugins = [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
        {
            name: ['common']
        }
    ),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: 'main.css'
    })
]

if (TARGET === 'start' || !TARGET) {
    module.exports = merge(common, {
        plugins: [
            ...commonPlugins,
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
        ],
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: {
                index: indexFile
            },
            hot: true,
            inline: true,
            stats: 'errors-only',
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: 8008,
            watchOptions: {
                ignored: /node_modules/,
                aggregateTimeout: 300,
                poll: 1000
            },
            disableHostCheck: true
        },
    })
}

if (TARGET === 'build') {
    var exports = merge(common, {
        plugins: [
            ...commonPlugins,
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                minimize: true,
                debug: false
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: '"production"'
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                screw_ie8: true,
                warnings: false,
                comments: false,
                mangle: true
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: './src/assets/reset.css' }
            ])
        ]
    })

    fs.readFile('./src'+indexFile, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var newIndex = data.toString().replace(/\/assets\//g, publicPath)
        fs.writeFile('./build/index.html', newIndex, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        })
    })

    console.log(util.inspect(exports, {showHidden: false, depth: null, colors: true}), '\n')
    module.exports = exports
}
```